# Swift, Eureka: Passing info backwards

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I am using Eureka to build the Settings page for my app. One of the rows will bring the user to a ProfileVC and allow the user to change his profile information (including an image and various String). The change will be updated in the `User` object which I store in CoreData. Upon going back to the SettingsVC, the SettingsHeaderView needs to be updated accordingly with the updated `User` object information.

In the Eureka form I use `row.presentationMode`. I am familiar with using delegate methods to pass info backwards between VCs, but when using Eureka, how do i do it?

My code as follows:

```
class SettingsViewController: FormViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {

form +++

        Section(){ section in
            section.header = {
                var header = HeaderFooterView<UIView>(.callback({
                    let view = HeaderViews.setUpSettingsHeaderView(user: self.user)
                    return view
                }))
                header.height = { 200 }
                return header
            }()
    }

       +++ Section()
        <<< ButtonRow("Profile") { (row: ButtonRow) in
            row.title = row.tag
            row.presentationMode = .segueName(segueName: "ToProfileVC", onDismiss: nil)
            })
```